# assign numbers to Ids

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const randId = "comment_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

const commentButton = document.createElement("section");
commentButton.id = randId;
commentButton.className = "comment2";

let IDArray = [];
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function addButtonClick() {
  if (numbers.length > 0) {
    randId;
    IDArray.push({ number: numbers++, id: randId });
    console.log(IDArray);
  }
}
addButtonClick();
```

Hello there, as you can see, randId generates a randomly generated Id and assigns this Id to my 'commentButton' element. I want to apply randId multiple times, so now I have many random Id's. Now I want to add these to the IDArray and assign one number from the 'numbers' Array to each ID, e.g. the first generated ID is 204 and it gets assigned 1, the second one is 407 and it gets assigned 2, the third one gets number 3 and so on...I am stuck with this issue, does somebody know, how this could be done?

I tried assigning the 'numbers' element to the randId, but it just assigned all numbers on each generated Id

Comment: You're assigning `randId` once, it naturally won't change magically...

Comment: A side note, but assigning random numbers to an element runs the risk of having duplicate IDs.  Would it not be better to use a sequence instead.

Comment: Put all generated ID's to array. Array index+1 is your number

Comment: Anyway, consider making `randId` a function instead, e.g. `const makeRandomId = () => "comment_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);`, and call it: `...id = makeRandomId();`

Comment: As an addition to @KScandrett comment. You could use [randomUUID()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID) to generate an unique id.

Comment: Also `numbers++` does not make sense, as `numbers` is an array. Maybe you meant `numbers.shift()`?

Comment: This comes across as an X/Y problem. WHY do you want to randomise the IDs?

Comment: And if you do need unique IDs, why not use [GUID/UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-do-i-create-a-guid-uuid)s?

Comment: thanks to you all for these ideas, I'll try one by one and see wich runs best

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things I am going to mention is already commented by our colleagues.
Your `randId` is not a function it is a variable you assigned it a value once. you should make it a function which returns a value whenever its called.

use some library like uuid to generate a unique id. if you want to avoid this, you can make an array with number generated within the function (which should come after "comment_") then check whether random generated IDs are already used and generate another one, in case it's used.

See my code

```
const usedIds = [];


const uniqueId = () => {
  let num;
  do {
    num = "comment_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  } while (usedIds.includes(num));
  
  usedIds.push(num);
  return num;
};



function addButtonClick() {
  if (numbers.length > 0) {
    const randId = uniqueId();
    IDArray.push({ number: numbers.shift(), id: randId });
    console.log(IDArray);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `randId` a function as shown and then you can use a `for-of` loop on `numbers` to generate the random ids as shown:

```js
const randId = () => "comment_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
const IDArray = [];
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function addButtonClick() {
  for(const number of numbers) {
    const id = randId();
    IDArray.push({ number, id });
    console.log(IDArray);
  }
}

addButtonClick();
```